# Zend Framework 3 DQL (doctrine’s language). SELECT, using of 2 tables (2 entities). How to get fields from the result?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, dql, zend-framework3, doctrine-query

In my Controller was DQL Select:

```
     $query = $this->entityManager->createQuery("SELECT cat 
FROM Application\Entity\Catalog cat 
WHERE cat.parent_id IS NULL AND cat.name IN (:names_ar)");
     $query->setParameter('names_ar', $equipment_categories);
     $catalog = $query->getResult();
```

Working greate!
But I need to add data from another Entity/table:

```
    $query = $this->entityManager->createQuery("SELECT cat, con 
FROM Application\Entity\Catalog cat, Application\Entity\Content con 
WHERE cat.parent_id IS NULL 
AND cat.name IN (:names_ar) 
AND cat.id = con.id");
```

I have connection of this tables in Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @Gedmo\TreePathSource
 * @ORM\Column(type="string");
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Content")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $id;
```

And second variant with JOIN:

```
    $query = $this->entityManager->createQuery("SELECT cat, con.sign 
FROM Application\Entity\Catalog cat 
INNER JOIN Application\Entity\Content con  
WHERE cat.parent_id IS NULL 
AND cat.name IN (:names_ar)");
```

Variants working without errors. But before I was taking data by

```
$catalog->fieldname;
```

Now last code not working. I do var_dump() of $catalog: 5-10 meters of data on my screen :( , as usually in the Zend, can't find the solution. I do not sure in DQL syntax, it's new for me.

Comment: Hard to read the question. Please format it so it's readable. Multiple lines for (DQL) queries would be a good start, as would removal of empty lines. Also, have you looked at [Criteria](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections) so that queries are generated for you? Could save a lot of hassle.

Comment: Done, about format. Thank you for your advice about Criteria! But I need to know, how to do it in DQL anyway.

Comment: Too many DQL in the project